# Use .htaccess to rewrite any subdomain to the corresponding subdir without revealing the subdir

Tags: domains, htaccess, subdomain

I have a little problem with my `.htaccess`. For example, if I go to `test.example.com`, it's in folder `/sub/test`. But it shows `test.example.com/sub/test`. How can I hide the path after `.com`? Or is there any way to do it with Apache, like all folders in `sub` folder are subdomains?

I don't know how to do it.

I'm using this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.).+?)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!sub/).*)$ /sub/%1/$1 [L]
```

**EDIT:** I want to make every created folder in `sub` folder as a subdomain automatically. Like user create folder and it's subdomain.

Comment: So, your subdomain's document root points to the root directory? And this is simply a wildcard subdomain I assume? Or have you configured this subdomain using a hosting control panel of some kind (eg. cPanel) and perhaps incorrectly set this as a "redirect"? The directives you posted won't do this by themselves. Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files? Check the network traffic, presumably you are seeing a 3xx redirect? What type?

Comment: htaccess isn't the right tool for the job.   You should move the directory structure and adjust your virtual hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your rules and just have something like:

```
<VirtualHost IP>
    ServerName test.example.com
    DocumentRoot /whatever/sub/test
```

(replace `whatever` by the correct path, and `IP` by the relevant IP/port based on how your virtualhosts are configured)

For dynamic virtual host have a look at module `mod_vhost_alias` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html), quoting from documentation:

```
For simple name-based virtual hosts you might use the 
following directives in your server configuration file:

UseCanonicalName    Off
VirtualDocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache/vhosts/%0"

A request for http://www.example.com/directory/file.html will be 
satisfied by the file
/usr/local/apache/vhosts/www.example.com/directory/file.html.
```

Otherwise, for your rewrite rules, it may work just by adding [P] as flag, but as a general rule I always recommend to find simpler ways to do things and use rewriting only if things can not be done otherwise (due to the complexity it adds).

Comment: Yes, but I want to make every created folder in sub folder as domain automatic. Like user create folder and it's subdomain without adding new virtualhost.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer: `mod_vhost_alias` permits you to do exactly what you describe. You configure it just once.